# Migrating from VS to GCC: change in use of typename?

Tags: visual-studio, stl, g++, typename

I'm building a large project on Debian 6.0.6 (with gcc 4.4.5) that was initially built in Microsoft VS (2008, I think).

What seems to be the problem is that when I declare a member as 
`typedef typename std::set<T>::iterator   iterator`, and then later use this iterator, gcc appears to interpret this as (const T*).

The part of the class containing the `typename` designation:

```
template <class entityType>
class entityArray
{
    private:                 std::set<entityType>             m_array;
    public: typedef typename std::set<entityType>::iterator   iterator;
 ...
    public:
        entityType*     At( const char* name);
 ...
};
```

plus a few other classes that are needed for the discussion:

```
class entity
{
    private:
        entity*     m_parent;
        int         m_ncid;
        std::string     m_name;
    public:
             entity () { m_ncid = 0; m_parent = NULL;}
    virtual ~entity () {};
 ...
};

class attribute : public entity
{
    public:
                   attribute(){};
        virtual   ~attribute(){};
};

class var : public entity
{
    private:
        entityArray<attribute>      m_atts;
    public:
                 var(){}
        virtual ~var(){}
       ...
};

class dim : public entity
{
    public:
                 dim() {};
        virtual ~dim() {};
};

class group : public entity
{
    private:
        entityArray<var>    m_vars;
        entityArray<dim>    m_dims;
...
    public:
        dim*     DimAt( const char* dimname )  { return m_dims.At(dimname);}
};
```

Now an `iterator` is initialized through a call to the function `DimAt` which in turn calls `At`.  The `At` function in the first class is defined as:

```
template <class entityType>
entityType* entityArray<entityType>::At( const char* name )
{
    entityType  dummy;
    iterator    iter;
    entityType* ptr;

    ... define dummy ...

    iter = m_array.find( dummy );
    ptr  = (iter != m_array.end()) ? &(*iter) : NULL;
    return ptr;
}
```

Compiling the above produces 
`error: invalid conversion from const dim* to dim*.`, referring to `&(*iter)`.
I realize that `typename` is required for declaring `iterator`, since the type is a dependent and qualified name, but I don't see why this substitution (`const *`) is being performed by the compiler. I would appreciate any help that you could provide.  Thanks!

Comment: ---comment deleted by author because it was lame---

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This has absolutely nothing to do with `typename`.

The standard allows `std::set<T>::iterator` and `std::set<T>::const_iterator` to be the same type, and with GCC the types are the same.

The reason is that modifying an element of a `std::set` e.g. by `*iter = val` might invalidate the ordering of the set elements, breaking the invariant that the elements of the set are always in order.  By making the `iterator` type a constant iterator instead of a mutable iterator it's not possible to alter the element, preventing you from corrupting the set's ordering.

So with GCC's implementation, when you dereference the iterator using `*iter` you get a `const entitType&` and when you take its address using `&*iter` you get a `const entityType*`